# what is the best way to achieve remote storage for users' files using django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, local-storage

What is the best storage server mechanism for the following requirements:

- The files that are going to be stored are encrypted and below 70MB
- Files have an identifier on the storage server
- I need the file to be retrieved very fast
- The storage server is in the same domain as as the django server
- The number of files being stored increases over time.

I have been suggested different methods like having a web server like apache or nginx to serve the files. Others also suchested using MongoDB as the storage server. I want the implementation be as simple as possible. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can try moving the file storage to Amazon S3 Storage, Django Boto (https://github.com/qnub/django-boto) helps in integration and easy to use. For Better performance i would suggest virtualenv, nginx with uWSGI link: 
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html